# Display the mac native print dialog box

Tags: macos, printing

I know I can print a PDF using lp or lpr but it just prints it without asking anything.
How can I instead trigger the mac native print dialog box programmatically (CLI, node.js if possible).
Many thanks!

Comment: https://www.cups.org/doc/options.html

Comment: How does this help with anything?